# How do I work on recursive postorder for this tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to work on the recursive post order and I have got the recursive preorder here and I am trying to make sure if I have got the recursive postorder correct?

For recursive preorder:

```
   void  preorderR (Tree &t){
   if (t.on()) {
      visit(t);
      t.descend();
      indent = indent + 3;
      while (t.on()) {
         preorderR(t);
         t.move();
      };
      t.ascend();
      indent = indent - 3;
   }

that gives

A
   D
      G
      F
      E
   C
      I
      H
   B
```

For recursive Postorder: ( am I following the correct pattern for Recursive)?

```
void  postorderR (Tree &t) {
   if (t.on()) {
      visit(t);
      t.descend();
      indent = indent + 3;
      t.ascend();
      indent = indent - 3;

while (t.on()) {
         postorderR(t);
         t.move();
      };


   }

the output that I need to get
             G
             F
             E
          D
             I
             H
          C
          B
       A
```

Comment: I recommend searching the internet for "C++ postorder recursive binary tree".  There are already a plethora of questions and answers about traversing a binary tree in postorder.

Comment: post a minimum reproducible example. People reading this do not automatically know what Tree::on(), etc. do. You can traverse in pre and post order with just a raw tree so it is unclear what the extra member functions are for.

Comment: also it is unclear what is generating the output. If `visit` is doing the printing how does it do the indenting since indent is not passed to visit? Is indent a member variable of the Tree class?